# Control order in which jars are added to shaded jar

Tags: maven, maven-3, maven-shade-plugin, uberjar, fatjar

I have found that the Confluent Kafka Connect addons only work if the jars are added to the classpath in a specific order.

Accordingly, I'm trying to build a single shaded jar that includes the jars, picking conflicting classes in the same order.

**My question is** How do I control the order in which jars are added to the shaded jar?

What I have discovered is that Maven processes jars in the following order:

1. First dependency specified in my pom
2. Dependencies of the pom from 1, in the order they appear in the pom, UNLESS that dependency exists in my pom, in which case it waits until its turn
3. Next dependency in my pom
4. 2 but as for the prior dependency
5. iterate 3-5 until all dependencies are processed.

I believe this based on the order jars are listed in the below list (list included for identification; I have truncated it as it is not especially illuminating):

```
[INFO] --- maven-shade-plugin:2.1:shade (default) @ kafka-connect-plus ---
[INFO] Including org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-common:jar:2.7.3 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Excluding com.google.guava:guava:jar:11.0.2 from the shaded jar.
[INFO] Excluding org.apache.commons:commons-math3:jar:3.1.1 from the shaded jar.
[INFO] Excluding xmlenc:xmlenc:jar:0.52 from the shaded jar.
[INFO] Excluding commons-httpclient:commons-httpclient:jar:3.1 from the shaded jar.
[INFO] Excluding commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.4 from the shaded jar.
[INFO] Excluding commons-net:commons-net:jar:3.1 from the shaded jar.
[INFO] Excluding javax.servlet:servlet-api:jar:2.5 from the shaded jar.
[INFO] Excluding org.mortbay.jetty:jetty:jar:6.1.26 from the shaded jar.
[INFO] Excluding org.mortbay.jetty:jetty-util:jar:6.1.26 from the shaded jar.
[INFO] Excluding javax.servlet.jsp:jsp-api:jar:2.1 from the shaded jar.
```

My shade plugin fragment:

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.1</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <phase>package</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>shade</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <artifactSet>
            <includes>
              <include>org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-common</include>
              <include>org.apache.avro:avro-ipc</include>
              <include>org.apache.parquet:parquet-avro</include>
              <include>io.confluent:kafka-avro-serializer</include>
              <include>org.apache.avro:avro</include>
              <include>org.apache.avro:avro-mapred</include>
              <include>io.confluent:kafka-connect-avro-converter</include>
              <include>io.confluent:kafka-schema-registry-client</include>
              <include>io.confluent:common-utils</include>
              <include>io.confluent:common-config</include>
            </includes>
          </artifactSet>
          <filters>
            <filter>
              <artifact>*:*</artifact>
              <excludes>
                <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
              </excludes>
            </filter>
          </filters>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```

(This is not yet a complete list of the jars).

As you can see from the above, the order of jar processing does not follow the order of `include` tags.

Answer (score 0):

Reading over my question again, I realise that the process above accomplishes exactly what I want, once I completed the process of whitelisting direct dependencies: I have the dependencies in the order they are specified in the dependencies section.